# One of my includes does not work

Tags: php

```
<?php  include ('doorrate.php'); ?>
<br />
<?php include ('shopbudget.php'); ?>
<br />
<?php include ('Graph_DLH.php'); ?>
<br />
<?php include ('overtime.php'); ?>
<br />
<?php include ('warranty.php'); ?>
```

the overtime.php will not work, but if I switch it to another position it will it's just anything that I place in that spot will not show. Now all of them will work individually it's just when I try It like this it does not on that one area

[image]

the blank section is what is missing

```
 <html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../CustomScripts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=3, minimum-scale=0.5" />
<?php
    //echo"{<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    //    window.onload = function () {
    //        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(\"chartContainer1\", {
    //            title: {
    //                text: \"Adding & Updating dataPoints\"
    //            },
    //            data: [
    //            {
    //                type: \"spline\",
    //                dataPoints: [
    //                    { y: 0.8109, label: \"April,  4, 2015\"},
    //                    { y: 0.7687, label: \"April, 11, 2015\" },
    //                    { y: 0.8223, label: \"April, 18, 2015\" },
    //                    { y: 0.7832, label: \"April, 25, 2015\" }
    //                ]
    //            }
    //            ]
    //        });
    //        chart.render();
    //    }
    //</script>"
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer1" style="height:35%; width: 100%; font-size:8px;"></div>
</body>

</html>




<?php   
$data_points= array();

$results=  "WITH MYTAB1 AS(
        SELECT  ITEM_NBR, LOCATION ,ITEM_DATE
        FROM IEGAR.KPI_FOREMAN_HIST
        WHERE ITEM_NBR=1100
        AND LOCATION='CHIIL'
        ORDER BY 3 DESC
        FETCH FIRST 13 ROWS ONLY
        )

        SELECT H.ITEM_NBR, H.ITEM_DATE, H.LOCATION  
        , H.ITEM_VALUE, H.KPI_COMMENT, H.CALC_DEF 
        FROM IEGAR.KPI_FOREMAN_HIST H 
        INNER JOIN MYTAB1 M ON H.ITEM_NBR=M.ITEM_NBR
        AND H.LOCATION =M.LOCATION
        AND H.ITEM_DATE=M.ITEM_DATE
        order by 2
        WITH UR";

$result=odbc_exec($bips, $results);


    //ITEM_DATE,ITEM_VALUE...?=LOCATION
          while($row= odbc_fetch_array($result))
        {    
            if($row['ITEM_DATE'] != null){
            //echo  $row['ITEM_DATE'];
            //echo  $row['ITEM_VALUE'];
            $point = array(label => $row['ITEM_DATE'], y => $row['ITEM_VALUE']*100);            
            array_push($data_points, $point);      
          }
            else
            {
                echo $point = array("label" => "ITEM_NBR", "y" => 0);
                array_push($data_points, $point); 
            }

          }
          //$display=json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
          //  echo $display;
          //echo json_encode($data_points);

odbc_close($bips);
?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            //$(document).ready(function () {
            //$.getJSON("Graph_DLH.php", function (result) {
            //chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = result;
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
                axisY: {
                    title: "Percentage",
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "column",
                        color: "#A8422A",
                        dataPoints:
                        [
                        { y: 0.70, label: "Mar-14" },
                        { y: 2.54, label: "Apr-14" },
                        { y: 3.26, label: "May-14" },
                        { y: 0.19, label: "June-14" },
                        { y: 4.00, label: "July-14" },
                        { y: 0.32, label: "Aug-14" },
                        { y: 0.08, label: "Sep-14" },
                        { y: 0.16, label: "Oct-14" },
                        { y: 0.24, label: "Nov-14" },
                        { y: 2.85, label: "Dec-14" },
                        { y: 0.74, label: "Jan-15" },
                        { y: 0.31, label: "Feb-15" },
                        { y: 1.16, label: "Mar-15" }]
                    }
                ],
                legend: {
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    itemclick: function (e) {
                        if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                        } else {
                            e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                        }
                        chart32.render();
                    }
                }
            });
            chart.render();

        //});
        };
        //});
    </script>
<body>
        <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 30%; width: 90%; font-size:8px;"></div>
 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
         //$(document).ready(function () {
         //$.getJSON("Graph_DLH.php", function (result) {
         //chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = result;
         var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer3", {
             title: {
                 text: "Warranty Chargeback & Rejections"
             },
             animationEnabled: true,
             axisX: {
                 interval: 1,
                 labelFontSize: 10,
                 lineThickness: 0
             },
             axisY2: {
                 FontSize: 14,
                 valueFormatString: "$ 0",
                 lineThickness: 0
             },
             toolTip: {
                 shared: true
             },
             legend: {
                 verticalAlign: "top",
                 horizontalAlign: "center"
             },

             data: [
                 {
                     type: "stackedBar",
                     showInLegend: true,
                     name: "Chargeback amount",
                     axisYType: "secondary",
                     color: "#A8422A",
                     dataPoints:
                     [
                     { y: 1810, label: "Mar-14" },
                     { y: 2222, label: "Apr-14" },
                     { y: 637, label: "May-14" },
                     { y: 541, label: "June-14" },
                     { y: 3446, label: "July-14" },
                     { y: 956, label: "Aug-14" },
                     { y: 429, label: "Sep-14" },
                     { y: 3589, label: "Oct-14" },
                     { y: 1789, label: "Nov-14" },
                     { y: 2594, label: "Dec-14" },
                     { y: 1206, label: "Jan-15" },
                     { y: 899, label: "Feb-15" },
                     { y: 3138, label: "Mar-15" }]
                 }
             ],
             legend: {
                 cursor: "pointer",
                 itemclick: function (e) {
                     if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                         e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                     } else {
                         e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                     }
                     chart22.render();
                 }
             }
         });
         chart.render();
         //});
     };
     //});
    </script>
<body>


        <div id="chartContainer3" style="height: 30%; width: 80%; padding-right:15%"></div>
 </body>
```

here is the code that I have for it

Comment: Any error you get? Besides that all those break lines are useless.

Comment: you're using camel case for Graph_DLH.php - could it be that overtime.php is really Overtime.php with an uppercase "O" ? on Linux if you're on that, letter-case is important. Two different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: Maybe some variable conflicts. You should try to include them from within a function so variables used in the files could not affect each other.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I just tried it but it's not giving me any errors It's like it's hiding or something and I'm not familiar of how to do them in a function

Comment: What did you have tried in-order to debug?

Comment: If I put it in an Iframe it works but Iframe does something screwy with the real estate and I can't get it to print off of one page

Comment: "anything in that spot" meaning any include you put after `<?php include ('Graph_DLH.php'); ?>` ?

Comment: that correct anything I put after will not show

Comment: Is it possible that Graph_DLH.php has something like die or exit?

Comment: In this case i would assume that the output of your `Graph_DLH.php` does something to prevent the next bit from displaying. I would start by removing that include. If that helps (for the others), i would continue by looking at the page source code to find out if something is there which is not rendered, after that, look at the lat bits of generated output in `Graph_DLH.php`.

Comment: I went through each one but no change